# c++ how to correctly reference a class attribute's value

Tags: c++, oop

I don't know exactly why this is happening but it seems that the code is "losing" the value of an attribute. I got a class defined as (in Foo.h):

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

using namespace std;
#include <string>

class Foo{
 public:
  Foo(short int id);
  void Foo::DoSomething(std::string someMsg);
 private:
  short int id;
};
#endif /* FOO_H */
```

in the class implementation (Foo.cpp):

```
#include "Foo.h"
#include <iostream>

Foo::Foo(short int id) {
 this->id = id;
 cout << "value now: " << this->id << "\n"; // I print to be sure it was set correctly and it prints the right value
}
void Foo::DoSomething(std::string someMsg) {
cout <<  "Foo number: " << std::to_string(this->id) << someMsg;
// when it runs this code called by another class, it always prints 0 to this->id for all objects instantiated
}
```

Then, I got another class, Bar. In Bar.h I have:

```
#ifndef BAR_H
#define BAR_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <list>
#include "Foo.h"

class Bar {
public:
 Bar();
 void setValor(std::string valor);
 void notifyAllFoos();
 void Bar::registerFoo(Foo *h);
private:
 std::list<Foo> foos;

};
#endif /* BAR_H */
```

In Bar.cpp I have:

```
#include "Bar.h"

void Bar::setValor(std::string valor){
 // do more stuff
 this->notifyAllFoos();
}

void Bar::registerFoo(Foo *h){
   this->foos.push_back(*h);
}

void Bar::notifyAllFoos(){
for(std::list<Foo>::iterator it=this->foos.begin() ; it!=this->foos.end() ; it++){
    it->DoSomething("myMsg");
 }
}
```

Finally, in main.cpp:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Bar.h"
#include "Foo.h"
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
 Bar *b = new Bar();

 b->registerFoo(new Foo(1));
 b->registerFoo(new Foo(2));
 b->registerFoo(new Foo(3));

 b->setValor("Value");
 delete b;
 return 0;
}
```

Basically, `Bar` must notify all `Foo`s of it's `list` that an update of an Value occured and print a Msg. To identify each `Foo` I put this `id` but it keeps printing 0 for all.
Why is this happening? It must be something very simple I guess but I'm not used to c++. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `this` refers to the instance, right? So you may as well present your `main()`. =)

Comment: Please check how to write [mcve]

Comment: Ideal example is one that you can copy and paste into your editor and run. This way you make sure you didn't omit an important part.

Comment: please show real code. Reducing it to make it easier is fine, but the code you show here wont print anything because it cannot compile. Such confusion can be avoided by providing a [mcve]

Comment: sorry for being pedantic, but your `Foo` has no `Foo::DoSomething`. Note that any single character someone else has to add to make it compile means that others are not looking at the same code as you do

Comment: `std::list<Foo> foos;` you store *copies* of objects. Given your code, I suppose you meant to store the exact object you passed. And you are not deleting `Foo`s after you create them via `new`.

Comment: offtopic: you dont need to convert numbers to strings before streaming them to the output. Simply `std::cout << this->id;` is fine

Comment: @Fabiotk sorry but can you provide a code that is accepted by the compiler? My test (after modify *lot of* things) do not reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Fabiotk [this code](http://ideone.com/C1XZRc) works as expected

Comment: well, but it doesn't work for me. That's why I opened the question! Could it be maybe compiler version? g++ 7.1.1 here. Or something else?

Comment: @Fabiotk then please post [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) your current code can not even compile.

Comment: Then it is time to reveal your compiler and command line you are using to compile. BTW: use compiler option /Wall or -Wall depending on your compiler.

Comment: @Fabiotk I'm using ``g++5.4.0`` with ``-Wall -Wextra -std=c++14 -pedantic`` as option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That:

```
std::list<Foo> foos;
```

will store *copies* of objects from class `Foo`.

You need to store pointers, like this:

```
std::list<Foo*> foos;
```

---

PS: Never forget to `delete` for every `new`, when you are done.

Comment: I think *default copy constructor* would copy the values as well.

Comment: The default copy constructor copy each member.

Comment: @gsamaras now your answer is not to the question anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I did take your code and put it into one file, added includes and using at the top and commented out declaration of Bar constructor.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class Foo{
 public:
  Foo(short int id);
  void Foo::DoSomething(std::string someMsg);
 private:
  short int id;
};

Foo::Foo(short int id) {
 this->id = id;
 cout << "value now: " << this->id << "\n"; // I print to be sure it was set correctly and it prints the right value
}
void Foo::DoSomething(std::string someMsg) {
cout <<  "Foo number: " << std::to_string(this->id) << someMsg;
// when it runs this code called by another class, it always prints 0 to this->id for all objects instantiated
}

#include <list>

class Bar {
public:
 //Bar();
 void setValor(std::string valor);
 void notifyAllFoos();
 void Bar::registerFoo(Foo *h);
private:
 std::list<Foo> foos;

};

void Bar::setValor(std::string valor){
 // do more stuff
 this->notifyAllFoos();
}

void Bar::registerFoo(Foo *h){
   this->foos.push_back(*h);
}

void Bar::notifyAllFoos(){
for(std::list<Foo>::iterator it=this->foos.begin() ; it!=this->foos.end() ; it++){
    it->DoSomething("myMsg");
 }
}

int main () {
Bar *b = new Bar();

b->registerFoo(new Foo(1));
b->registerFoo(new Foo(2));
b->registerFoo(new Foo(3));

b->setValor("Value");

}
```

It gives me following output

```
value now: 1
value now: 2
value now: 3
Foo number: 1myMsgFoo number: 2myMsgFoo number: 3myMsg
```

Is it what you are looking for?